# Where to place test/bats files

Tags: bats-core

Where is the best place to put the bats aka test files? Do you put them in the same directory as the bash scripts you are testing? If you put them in a different directory how do you reference the bash scripts?

Comment: I do not know the best place, but I use a separate test folder next to the scripts folder, like bats-core store the used bats files. But my fixtures folder is not in the test folder, it is next to the test and script folder also.

Answer (score 1):

To run a script in a different folder, I add the folder to the "run" statement also.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

MY_SCRIPT='post.sh'

@test "no argument prints usage instruction" {
  run ./scripts/$MY_SCRIPT
  [ $status -eq 0 ]
  [ "${lines[0]}" == 'Usage: post.sh {start|stop|restart|status|logfile}' ]
  [ "${lines[0]%% *}" == 'Usage:' ]
}
```

The tested script "post.sh" is in the folder ./scripts and the used test "post.bats" is in the folder ./test, next to the folder with the scripts. I start the tests from the folder where the ./scripts and ./test folder is.